# Http Header setting issue

Tags: java, html, header

How to add *Cache-Control property* in *Http Response*, I am working on code base where front end is completely **JavaScript/Jquery** , and back end a java I am not able to get where to add & what code to add to see *Cache-Control* set to *no-cache*, I followed some web-links but still  no luck.

1. I tried adding code is **JavaScript** as below to load it dynamically when web page gets rendered but not working:

   `('head').append('<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Cache-Control">')`
2. I tried adding a filter in **web.xml** but that also not working.

**UPDATE**

In this Pic I can see the Header is added but still the js file is getting cached.

[image]

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, yes i got a use full link and able to make changes but still I cannot find them in effect..:(  Please check this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1wU2W.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With Java EE6+ you should just write a filter with a @WebFilter annotation and set the HTTP headers to the response. Here is a filter you can use. Beware that the header is not overridden afterward.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class HttpHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // Nothing to do.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        res.setHeader("cache-control", "private, max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 12);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Nothing to do.
    }

}
```

To disable caching, you should use the following headers.

```
final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
// HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
// HTTP 1.0.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
// Proxies.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```